# How can I write a case sensitive WHERE CLAUSE in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, case-sensitive, sql-server-2019

Ok, this one has me stumped.  I'm hoping it's not something stupid/obvious...

I'm trying to fix addresses in a client database.  I have a function that takes a string and returns a string where the first letter of every word is capitalized.

I am trying to only pass the addresses that are all caps, or all lowercase, but it's returning the entire dataset instead.  The first three columns are all correct, so I can't figure out why the *WHERE* isn't working.

Here's my code.

```
    SELECT
        [ConvertFirstLettertoCapital]([Address]) AS [Standard],
        UPPER([Address]) AS [Upper],
        LOWER([Address]) AS [Lower],
        [Name],
        [Address],
        [Address 2],
        [City],
        [State]
    FROM [Address_List]
    WHERE
        [Address] = UPPER([Address]) OR
        [Address] = LOWER([Address])
```

- SQL Server v15.0.1083.2
- [SQL Server Management Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) v15.0.18330

Comment: What collation is your database / table set to?  Your WHERE clause will match the entire column if your collation is one of the non-case-sensitive collations which is frequently the case in MSSQL.

Comment: If the database is in a case insensitive (and accent insensitive) collation, then it'll return every row where `Address` has a not `NULL` value. *Normally* databases are case insensitive, and only use a case sensitive when you really need it; seeing you don't state it is in one I doubt it is. Thus `'my àddrêss'` = `'MY ADDRESS'`.

Comment: @squillman It's 'COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'   I am guessing that CI = Case Insensitive

Comment: That is correct, CI = Case Insensitive.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally SQL Server is not case sensitive. So `'ABC'='abc'` is true in a `where clause`.

To make a `where` clause case sensitive, you can use `COLLATE`. Please try the below query instead:

```
WHERE
        [Address] = UPPER([Address]) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
        OR
        [Address] = LOWER([Address]) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```